# Event sent by Windows when connected to internet

Tags: c++, windows, events, networking

I need to know in my program when the connection to internet is back.

Actually I can check if it is connected with something like

```
CComPtr<INetworkListManager> pNLM;
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_NetworkListManager, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, __uuidof(INetworkListManager), (LPVOID*)&pNLM);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    VARIANT_BOOL isConnected;
    pNLM->get_IsConnectedToInternet(&isConnected);
    if (isConnected == VARIANT_TRUE)
```

But I cannot find a nice way to get informed that the connection is back.
Polling is not a nice way, to me.

I've found `::NotifyAddrChange()` but this is triggered whenever change occurs in the table that maps IPv4 addresses to interfaces.

Is there a specific event that is sent when the connection is established?

Comment: You probably need to implement and register the [INetworkEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/netlistmgr/nn-netlistmgr-inetworkevents) interface. While implementing the interface looks to be pretty straight forward, I have no idea how you would register it.

Comment: Or is it the [INetworkListManagerEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/netlistmgr/nn-netlistmgr-inetworklistmanagerevents) interface? Regardless, I have no idea how to register your callbacks, and - true to all other COM documentation - there's literally **nothing** that describes the overall structure of the system. Something like a less useless version of the [Network List Manager Architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/nla/network-list-manager-architecture) would go a long way.

Comment: I didn't know that my colleague did this in the past so I got the code from him. I will add an answer ASAP because will be useful for others, there's no documentation about it from MS

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to a colleague of mine, I have the answer.

This is the class that will call the callback

```
#include "Event.h"

Event::Event(const std::function<void()>& cb)
    : methodTobeCalled(cb)
{
}

HRESULT Event::NetworkConnectionConnectivityChanged(GUID, NLM_CONNECTIVITY)
{
    if (methodTobeCalled)
        methodTobeCalled();

    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT Event::NetworkConnectionPropertyChanged(GUID, NLM_CONNECTION_PROPERTY_CHANGE)
{
    return S_OK;
}

STDMETHODIMP Event::QueryInterface(REFIID refIID, void** pIFace)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    *pIFace = nullptr;
    if (IsEqualIID(refIID, IID_IUnknown))
    {
        *pIFace = (IUnknown *)this;
        ((IUnknown *)*pIFace)->AddRef();
    }
    else if (IsEqualIID(refIID, IID_INetworkConnectionEvents))
    {
        *pIFace = (INetworkConnectionEvents *)this;
        ((IUnknown *)*pIFace)->AddRef();
    }
    else
    {
        hr = E_NOINTERFACE;
    }

    return hr;
}

ULONG Event::AddRef(void)
{
    return static_cast<ULONG>(InterlockedIncrement(&m_ref));
}

ULONG Event::Release(void)
{
    LONG Result = InterlockedDecrement(&m_ref);
    return static_cast<ULONG>(Result);
}
```

In the ctor of the main class (no error handling here):

```
::CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
::CoCreateInstance(CLSID_NetworkListManager, nullptr, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_INetworkListManager, (LPVOID *)&m_pNLM);
m_pNLM->QueryInterface(IID_IConnectionPointContainer, (void **)&m_pCpc);
m_pCpc->FindConnectionPoint(IID_INetworkConnectionEvents, &m_pConnectionPoint);
m_event = std::make_unique<NetworkEvent>(std::bind(&MainClass::methodTobeCalled, this));
hr = m_pConnectionPoint->Advise((IUnknown *)m_event.get(), &m_cookie);
```

The variables needed:

```
std::unique_ptr<NetworkEvent> m_event;
DWORD m_cookie;
CComPtr<IConnectionPoint> m_pConnectionPoint;
CComPtr<INetworkListManager> m_pNLM;
CComPtr<IConnectionPointContainer> m_pCpc;
```

The method that will be called at each network event, will be

MainClass::methodTobeCalled()

In this method one can then check if the connection is available or not.
O can check the NLM_CONNECTIVITY flags in NetworkConnectionConnectivityChanged()

Comment: Oh, right, would have been helpful to have this in the documentation. As always, Raymond Chen has helpful information on the topic: [An introduction to COM connection points](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130611-00/?p=4113).